# Regex not validating correctly

Tags: php, regex

So i have spent the last hour or so trying to construct a regex pattern that follows these rules:

- Must be between 3-15 characters long
- Must start and end with a letter
- Can contain spaces and underscores but cannot contain consecutive space or underscore

This is the code:

```
preg_match("/^(?!.*__.*)(?!.*\s\s.*)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_\s]{3,15}[A-Za-z]$/",$n_username)
```

However for some reason "administrator" is invalid, however "administrator1" is valid

Could someone please point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: The regex is good, at least with the two examples you provided.

Comment: check the regex101.com

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer just to implement separate non-regex checks for each of those constraints?

Comment: please let me use any username\password i want

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? http://regex101.com/r/uY3eS8/2

Comment: Works correctly here: http://ideone.com/2wMr6Q

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." – Barmar, Book Of Zeus, Ghost, Divi, Robby Cornelissen ............ Pretty sure i cover all those. Just that there are too many people on this community up their own backside... However, thanks to everyone that helps. Got it working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uY3eS8/3), even though it is inefficient and technically will match 5-17 characters. I cleaned up the expression for you:

```
^(?=[a-z])(?:\w|\s(?!\s)|_(?!_)){3,15}(?<=[a-z])$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/tX2jO3/1) *(requires `i` modifier or changing `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`)*

---

Although, there is a good chance you are having problems with how [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) works. The part that matters to us is that it returns an integer of the number of matches. We can loosely match this to a boolean in a conditional statement to see if there is a successful match:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?=[a-z])(?:\w|\s(?!\s)|_(?!_)){3,15}(?<=[a-z])$/i', $n_username)) {
    // match found
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

---

**Explanation**

```
^(?=[a-z])   (?# anchor to the beginning of string and lookahead for a letter)
(?:          (?# begin non-capturing group for repetition)
  \w         (?# word character, [a-zA-Z0-9_])
 |           (?# OR)
  \s(?!\s)   (?# whitespace character, [ \t\r\n\f], not followed by whitespace)
 |           (?# OR)
  _(?!_)     (?# _ not followed by a _)
){3,15}      (?# repeat the above group 3-15 times)
(?<=[a-z])$  (?# anchor to the end of string and lookbehind for a letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

First part is a negative regex (consecutive space or _)

```
(?!.*([\s_]{2,}).*)
```

2nd part is a classic Regex (warn if you want one letter starting and ending, you can have only one letter mid)

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_\s]{1,13}[A-Za-z]$
```

So we have

```
$regex= "(?!.*([\s_]{2,}).*)^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_\s]{1,13}[A-Za-z]$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone commented above about just implementing manual checks for the constraints. I just wanted to show what this would look like and am not in anyway suggesting that this be implemented over matching with regex.

```
function isValidInput($string){
    $length = strlen($string);
    if ($length < 3 || $length > 15) return false;
    if (!ctype_alpha(substr($string, 0, 1)) || !ctype_alpha(substr($string, $length-1, 1))) return false;
    if (strpos($string, '  ') || strpos($string, '__')) return false;
    return true;
}
```